# Looking For Most Frequent Values SQL Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
id | Unit_Ids
1  | {"unit_ids" : ["5442","28397"]}
2  | {"unit_ids" : ["5442","3492","2290"]}
etc.
```

And I'm trying to find the most frequently appearing values in Unit_Ids. As in my example 5442 appears in both lines 1 and 2, it would be the most frequent value. I was just having trouble finding a good way of creating this statement.

Thank you in advanced!

EDIT: Sorry everyone I'm working with MySQL

Comment: Is there any way you can normalize the data in the table?

Comment: Is `Unit_Ids` supposed to be a string representing a JSON? You should look into a one-to-many relationship with a separate table (or the same table with a composite key of `id` and `unit_id`, assuming that these are the only 2 columns in the table). There's a reason why it's difficult to query non-atomic values

Comment: Which is your database - MS SQL Server, MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: I removed all database tags since it should be tagged with the specific database engine.

Comment: [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0):

If 2016+

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([id] int,[Unit_Ids] varchar(max))  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'{"unit_ids" : ["5442","28397"]}')
,(2,'{"unit_ids" : ["5442","3492","2290"]}')


Select top 1 value 
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply OpenJSON([Unit_Ids],'$.unit_ids') R 
 Order By sum(1) over (partition by value) desc
```

**Returns**

```
value
5442
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you are storing JSON strings in the `Unit_Ids` field. If you do that, you won't be able to extract or aggregate data stored in that field.

You can however create a child table and query it to get aggregated data. Ie:

```sql
-- Master table
create table parent(id number primary key);

-- List of units per parent
create table units(
    id number not null,
    parent_id number not null,

    primary key (id, parent_id),
    foreign key (parent_id) references parent(id)
);

-- Insert sample data
insert into parent values 1;
insert into parent values 2;

insert into units(parent_id, id) values(1, 5442);
insert into units(parent_id, id) values(1, 28397);
insert into units(parent_id, id) values(2, 5442);
insert into units(parent_id, id) values(2, 3492);
insert into units(parent_id, id) values(2, 2290);

-- Count the number of times a unit id is in the table
select id, count(id) from units group by id;
```

Comment: On what basis are you making that assumption?

Comment: The assumption is based on the output of the query from the question (that list the values of a column as JSON), and the expected result (the maximum number of occurrences of a value).